# How to handle resizing the screen with Angular Animations?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, responsive-design, media-queries

How do you handle resizing the window with Angular Animations properties like width?
For example:
This code will animate the width of an element and for all sizes will not flood off screen or look too small.

Desktop:

[image: intended]

mobile:

[image: intended2]

Until the user resizes the screen.  On resize the animation is completed and therefore will not react to the window resize.

[image]

```
function setEndWidth() {
  if(MatchMediaService.bp('sm')){
    return '70vw';
  } else {
    return '30vw';
  }
}

function setStartWidth() {
  if(MatchMediaService.bp('sm')){
    return '0px';
  } else {
    return '20vw';
  }
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'menu-container',
  templateUrl: 'menu.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('goodmorning', [
      state('void', style({
        'width': '0',
        'transform': 'rotate(0)',
        'transform-origin': '0 0'
      })),
      state('harwood', style({
        'width': setEndWidth(),
        'transform': 'rotate(-30deg)',
        'transform-origin': '0 0'
      })),
      transition('void => *', animate(2000, keyframes([
        style({
          'width': '0',
          'transform': 'rotate(0)',
          'transform-origin': '0 0'
        }),
        style({
          'width': setStartWidth(),
          'transform': 'rotate(0)',
          'transform-origin': '0 0'
        }),
        style({
          'width': setEndWidth(),
          'transform': 'rotate(-30deg)',
          'transform-origin': '0 0'
        })
      ]))),
      transition('void => *', animate('2.5s 0s cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955)'))
    ])
  ]
})
```

HTML:

```
<line-thing [@goodmorning]="'harwood'"></line-thing>
```

Comment: Do not use dimensions in pixel if you want the size to depend on the screen width. Use percentages or `vw` instead.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I'm still confused on why but when I use vw and resize the window it still won resize the element's final state

Comment: Try to use dynamic input parameters instead of setting the properties as you did in the example. Setting style properties only set them when the animation starts while dynamic input parameters should change during runtime. You can look at dynamic input parameters in Matias' post: https://www.yearofmoo.com/2017/06/new-wave-of-animation-features.html#how-to-use-animation-input-parameters